# State change for an unknown number of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question starts from the code below, as you see, when i write something in my FormInput component, the state changes accordingly

```
class GroupsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name:''
    }
  }

handleChange = event => {
    const{name,value} = event.target;
    this.setState({[name]:value})
}

render(){
    return(
    <div className='groups-page'>
      <div className='new-group'>
                    <div className='join-group'>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleJoinSubmit}>
                            <FormInput name='code' type='text' value={this.state.code} handleChange={this.handleChange} label='Group Code' required/>
                            <CustomButton type='submit'>Join Group</CustomButton>
                        </form>
                    </div>
      </div>
  </div>)}
};
```

What i want to do is to use this template to create something like google forms, in other words:
have a component in which i write the question , possible answers, and select the right one

My question would be, how can i update the code above , to be able to update the state for an initially unknown number of questions? Should i use an array of components? And if so, how can i update a specific item from the array when a change occurs?

Comment: With this terms 'unknown number of questions' , you should have questions in an array. So, 
You can map the questions and render the same component, when you map you have the index so you can access/identify each items by the index and change its value then setState

Comment: Interesting, i see that working @Abrah_dago_313

Comment: Cool, happy coding Williams

Comment: Abrah_dago_313 is on the correct track, but I would caution you against using array indices to identify array elements considering you are adding to and updating the array. You should assign a GUID to each element entry (i.e. question) that uniquely identifies it. It sounds like you've not tried anything yet and are just probing for ideas, this will yield opinionated responses. Try to narrow the focus of your question to a specific issue.

Comment: You are right @DrewReese, i'm thinking what would be the best way to implement this. And for you suggestion, I will search some examples for what you are suggesting, since i don't know much about it.

Comment: If you were to update your question here with a more representative code example of entering and rendering an array of questions we can likely provide better help if you're stuck or have any issues.

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese , will sure do